# How to Specify Width and Height of a Flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I have a flextable that I would like to modify the length and width of to create a 3.5in x 3.5in table. I've tried looking around, but have so far found no easy way of manipulating table dimensions. Is anyone aware of a way to specify flextable length and height

Example code

```
library(flextable)

#read in data
data(mtcars)

#create flextable
ft<-flextable(mtcars[1:10,1:11])
ft

#save flextable
ft %>% save_as_image("../PATH/NAME.png")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save your flextable as a plot, you should use package 'ragg' and command `plot()`(or `gen_grob()`).

```
library(flextable)

#read in data
data(mtcars)

#create flextable
ft <- flextable(mtcars[1:10,1:11])
ft

#save flextable
ragg::agg_png(filename = "test.png", width = 3.5, height = 3.5, units = "in", res = 200)
plot(ft)
dev.off()
```

[image]